# Using CopyFile with RemoteFile + SSH

Tags: remote-access

If I have a file at address `/path/to/file` with SSH address `192.168.0.11`, username `user` and password `password`, then how can I do something like

```
a = RemoteFile["192.168.0.11:/path/to/file",
 Authentication -> <|"Username" -> "user", "Password" -> "password"|>]

CopyFile[a, CloudObject["file"]]
```

? This evaluates to `$Failed` on my machine. I suspect the way I'm entering the SSH path is wrong?

Comment: The first argument to `RemoteFile` should be a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), and yours is not. For instance, here is an example from the docs: `"sftp://host.example.com/tmp/test.m"`. See also [`URL`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URL.html) in the docs.

Comment: MarcoB: Thanks for the lead. I've tried different combinations from the doc, but so far have been unable to convert my SSH path to an acceptalbe `URL[..]` that doesn't generate an error when attempting to use `CopyFIle`.